# PHP Login always returning an error

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm using MySqli prepared statements to do this one. There is no password for this. I am making this for a friend, who is a teacher. I want students to be able to type in their ID without a password to gain access to a page where they can check out books, return books, view statuses etc. 
Here is my code:

functions.php:

```
<?php
function check_login() {
 $host = "localhost";
 $user = "root";
 $pass = "password";
 $data = "login";
 $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $data);
 if ($stmt = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM students WHERE id=?")) {
  $stmt -> bind_param("s", $sid);
  $stmt -> execute();
  $stmt -> store_result();
  if($stmt -> num_rows() == "1") {
   $_SESSION['sid'] = $sid;
   $_SESSION['logged'] = "yes";
   $stmt -> close();
   header("Location: index.php");
  }
  else
  {
   echo "Wrong Username/Password Combo";
  }
 }
}
```

login.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sid'])) {
$sid = $_POST['sid'];
include "functions.php";
session_start();
check_login();
}
else {
echo '          <form role="form" action="login.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group"><label for="sid">Student ID</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sid" name="sid" placeholder="Enter Student ID"></div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
          </form>';
}
```

P.S. A lot of the echo's and html were just snip-its, I just didn't want to paste the whole HTML echo here.

Comment: What error do you get? What does mysqli_error() say?

Comment: @JohnConde you have to run his code and see where is the error :).

Comment: You need to pass variable to `check_login()` like `check_login($sid)`

Comment: So in the functions.php, should i replace function check_login() with function check_login($sid) and do the same in login.php?

Comment: yes you have to other wise you need to define it as global

Comment: Sidenote: `session_start();` needs to be inside all pages using sessions. It's not in your `functions.php` code; not posted anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$sid` is out of scope for your `check_login()` function. To make it in scope you need to pass it as a parameter:

```
check_login($sid);
```

You can also use the `global` keyword inside of your function but that is discouraged a bad programming practice.

Read more about [variable scope at the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your check_login function with $sid as a parameter

```
    function check_login($sid){
        ...
    }
```

And then pass the value in when you call it

```
    $sid = $_POST['sid'];
    include "functions.php";
    session_start();
    check_login($sid);
```